# How exactly do I parse/separate a single element of an array based on a certain number of digits?

Tags: java

How exactly do I separate a single grouping of numbers in Java in a string of digits that contains more than 1 or 2 digits? For example, I need to only separate the digits in the groups larger than 1 or 2 digits in this string: 12,10,12914,10,641,10,11,11,2,10.

Also, how can I separate/split certain elements in an array in Java without separating all of the elements? For example, I need to separate the letters from the numbers, and separate the 12 from the 9, and the 6 from the 4 in this set of elements:
[12a, 129, 14a, 64, 1a, 11b, 2a].

Thanks for any help!

Comment: About the first String, why can't you just split the String by comma, and select the values you want?  About the second String, it appears that you want to separate the last character from the prior characters.  Why can't you split the String by comma, space and then separate each part into one or more characters and single character?

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string since they are comma separate and then loop through each of the numbers and separate only those that meet your criteria.

```
   String str = "12,10,12914,10,641,10,11,11,2,10";
   str[] ary = str.split(",");
   for (str s : ary) {
     if ( s.length() > 1 ) {
       //separate the contents of the string as you want
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

In the first case:

- split the string on `,` possibly surrounded by white space.
- filter strings > length of 2
- convert to an Integer and store in a list.

```
String s1 = "12,10,12914,10,641,10,11,11,2,10";

List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(s1.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
        .filter(str -> str.length() > 2).map(Integer::valueOf)
        .toList();

System.out.println(list1);
```

Prints

```
[12914, 641]
```

In the second case

- split the same way as before.
- convert the string sans the last character (letter or digit) to an integer. This uses the `String.substring` method.
- return in a list.

```
String s2 = "2a, 129, 14a, 64, 1a, 11b, 2a";
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.stream(s2.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
        .map(str -> Integer.valueOf(
                str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)))
        .toList();
System.out.println(list2);
```

Prints

```
[2, 12, 14, 6, 1, 11, 2]
```

In the second case an exception will be thrown if the items end in more than one non-digit character or are not at least 2 in length.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps you

```
public class Main
{
    
    public static String example1(int[] in) {
        
        String msg = "Example 1\n";
        
        for(int idx=0; idx<in.length; idx++) {
            
            msg += in[idx] + ":";
            String str=String.valueOf(in[idx]);
            boolean split = false;
            
            for(int i=1; i<str.length(); i++) {
                
                char x = str.charAt(i-1);
                char y = str.charAt(i);
                
                
                if (x!=y && i == 1) {
                    
                    msg += " " + x;
                    
                } 
                
                if (x!=y) { 
                    
                    msg += " " + y;
                    
                }
                
                
                
            }
            
            msg += "\n";
            
        }
        
        msg += "Done";
        return msg;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] in = new int[] {12,10,12914,10,641,10,11,11,2,10};        
        String msg = example1(in);
        System.out.println(msg);
        
    }
    
}
```